# Jquery Not Grabbing Newest Input Value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Currently, I am creating a search bar. Anyhow I am grabbing the input value, but the problem is it is not always grabbing what I want it to grab. Let me explain some more.

The place where I run into issues is when I update the input value with the dropdown value. I will get into the code after, but simply when submitting the text in the query it will only grab what the user inputted. So if a user clicks on a dropdown value, it will not submit that, it will submit only what the user entered for some reason.

---

**Code Time!!!**

*HTML*

```
<input type="text" name="search" class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-3" id="searchbar" autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo $query; ?>"/>
<button class="glyphicon glyphicon-search glyphicon-non-button col-xs-2 col-sm-1" id="searchbarbutton" input type="submit"> </button>
<div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-3" id="postsearchsuggestionholder">
    <div class="postsearchsuggestion col-xs-12" id="postsearchsuggestion1"></div>
</div>
```

*Javascript (Jquery too)*

```
//Adds the Query to the URL

$("[name='searchform']").change(function() {
        $("[name='searchform']").attr("action", "http://localhost/postin'/categories/<?php echo $category; ?>/" + $("#searchbar").val().trim());
});

//Removes the dropdown
$("#searchbar").keyup(function() {
    if ($("#searchbar").val().length == 0) {
        $("#postsearchsuggestionholder").hide();
        $('#searchbar').css("border-bottom-left-radius","3px");
    }
});

//Dropdown stuff (Autocomplete stuff)
$(function() {
    $("#searchbar").autocomplete({
        source: function(request,response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost/postin'/categories/searchbar.php",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                data: { 'keyword': request.term,
                        'category': "<?php echo strtolower($category); ?>" },
                success: function(data) {
                    if (0 in data) {
                        $('#postsearchsuggestionholder').show();
                        $('#searchbar').css("border-bottom-left-radius","0px");
                        $('#postsearchsuggestion1').text(data[0]);
                        $('#postsearchsuggestion1').show();
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#postsearchsuggestion1').hide();
                    }
                    $("#postsearchsuggestion1").click(function() {
                        $('#searchbar').val(data[0]);
                        $('#postsearchsuggestionholder').hide();
                        $('#searchbar').css("border-bottom-left-radius","3px");
                    });
                }
            });
        },
    });
});
```

---

**So Simply,** if a user types in `hel` then it might for instance suggest `hello`, but it will still search `hel`, and I am not sure why. Any ideas? Thank You!

---

**EDITED**
Shortened down the code.

Comment: Did you make sure that after press enter after suggestion is shown ? Because if suggestion does not take the value property than hel is still the input value.

Comment: Hmm yea, I am basically setting the inputs' value as the suggested value. Then when the user clicks search, it is grabbing the fields value. It works **AFTER** the suggested is put into the input, and then I edit the input. So I am not sure...

Comment: Plese reduce your code to only what is relevant to the question. There is no need to show numerous duplicate event handlers that basically all do the same thing

Comment: Code shown with updates.

Comment: if you use the web inspector in your browser, does the value on the search input change?

Comment: Submitting the form with the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the answer lies in the fact that `val()` doesn't trigger a `change` event.  Try this: (*note the second line has changed from yours*)

```
...
$("#postsearchsuggestion1").click(function() {
    $('#searchbar').val(data[0]).trigger("change");
    $('#postsearchsuggestionholder').hide();
    $('#searchbar').css("border-bottom-left-radius","3px");
});
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Move click function out of the autocomplete function and use "on". Change:

```
$("#postsearchsuggestion1").click(function() {
                    $('#searchbar').val(data[0]);
                    $('#postsearchsuggestionholder').hide();
                    $('#searchbar').css("border-bottom-left-radius","3px");
                });
```

to look like this:

```
$(body).on("#postsearchsuggestion1","click",function(){
                   $('#searchbar').val(data[0]);
                    $('#postsearchsuggestionholder').hide();
                    $('#searchbar').css("border-bottom-left-radius","3px");
 });
```

I used body but you can set any parent div to be "watched" by on. Here is the doc. http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: I like your answer. You are right the click method should be moved out of the autocomplete,  but it doesn't fix the issue he's having.